# Programmatically default Kendo UI DropDownListFor() to .OptionLabel selection

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

If we have two Kendo UI DropDownListFor's bound to data in an MVC ViewModel passed from the Controller, if a user makes a selection in one of the dropdown's, how can we default the other to the `.OptionLabel("` selection?

```
    @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.Cat)
    .Name("CatsDropDownList")
    .BindTo(Model.Cats)
    .OptionLabel("- Cats -")
    .Events(e => e.Change("CatsDropdownChangeHandler"))
)

@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.Dog)
    .Name("DogsDropDownList")
    .BindTo(Model.Dogs)
    .OptionLabel("- Dogs -")
    .Events(e => e.Change("DogsDropdownChangeHandler"))
)

function CatsDropdownChangeHandler() {
    //do something
}

function DogsDropdownChangeHandler() {
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function CatsDropdownChangeHandler() {
        //do something
        $("#DogsDropDownList").data("kendoDropDownList").value(null);
    }

    function DogsDropdownChangeHandler() {
        //do something
        $("#CatsDropDownList").data("kendoDropDownList").value(null);
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific API function to set the `OptionLabel`, you can simply select index 0 (Optionlabel value) as:

```
@section scripts{
    <script>

        function CatsDropdownChangeHandler(e) {

            var dropdownlist = $("#DogsDropDownList").data("kendoDropDownList");            
            dropdownlist.select(0);        
        }

        function DogsDropdownChangeHandler(e) {
            var dropdownlist = $("#CatsDropDownList").data("kendoDropDownList");
            dropdownlist.select(0);
        }        
    </script>

    }
```

Alternatively, you can [set text](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/dropdownlist#methods-text) of dropdown. If you love ajax binding :), you can [refresh](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/dropdownlist#methods-refresh) the dropdowns in turn.

Comment: This worked great! However @Jayesh Goyani was 2 minutes quicker. Thank you both.